# How to iterate over Mysql database query using Python?

Tags: python, mysql, loops

I want to run a query on MySql Database by iterating over it. I get the output from ML classifier which I need to store in my database. Here *pred* is the result from the classifier. I am trying to iterate like this-

```
for i in range(len(pred)):
    cursor.execute("UPDATE my_table SET status = %s WHERE status is null;", pred[i])
```

But it gives me this error-

```
TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable
```

And the same error on other attempts as well, like-

```
for num in pred:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE cc_jobboard_job_application SET status = %s WHERE status is null;", num)
```

Similarly, I have tried saving this pred into dataframe then iterating over it and also used enums for the purpose.
This code is doing well for single values as I do not have to get it into any loop. How can I appropriately iterate over this update query?

Comment: You know that you could have used `for item in pred:` and just `item` as the argument of the query?

Comment: Except apparently pred is an int. Why are you trying to iterate over it?

Comment: pred is a tuple @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `execute`'s second argument needs to be a tuple even if the query has a single parameter.
2. Your loop is not very pythonic and can be simplified. Instead of iterating over the range of the indexes, directly iterate over the elements.

   ```
   for num in pred:
       cursor.execute("UPDATE my_table SET status = %s WHERE status is null;", (num,))
   ```